# ASP.NET _doPostBack from Javascript

Tags: asp.net

The follow code does not work in IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            $(":text[id*=txtPopCEP]").keypress(function(e){
                  var tecla = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keycode;
                  if(tecla == 13)
                  {
                      __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1', '');

                  }
            });
    });
</script>
```

It doenst call the doPostBack function.But in FF it works...Any ideias?

ImageButton1 code output:

```
    <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton1" src="imagens/btCEP.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

Comment: can you paste in the actual HTML output to the client for ImageButton1 ? ~ and you can probably just stick with e.keycode

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="imagens/btCEP.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="btnPopCEP_Click" />

Comment: @user257234 that is what is written in your source files. can you view the output in the browser? also try it without the e.which stuff

Comment: hmmm, I don't see a __doPostBack() attached to the HTML, but try just using var tecla = e.keycode; first

Comment: ive removed e.which,but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IE doesn't like the ":text[id*=txtPopCEP]" conditional in JQuery.

I suggest adding: `CssClass="txtPopCEP"` 
to the ImageButton...

Then making your conditional `$(".txtPopCEP")`

Comment: the problem isnt in selector,because its getting correct textbox,the problem is with the __doPostBack function

Comment: Another issue could be is that you're using a hard coded ClientId

Comment: I would suggest having the code behind populate the JavaScript with a ImageButton1.ClientId

Answer (score 0):

`__doPostBack` dont work directly with image and buttons. Add the `onclick` through `aspx.cs` page.
For intance check below code:

```
script = "javascript:return popUpCalendar(this," + txtEndDate.ClientID + @",'" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + @"','" + EstartDate + @"','" + EendDate + @"',  'mm/dd/yyyy',  '__doPostBack(\'" + txtStartDate.ClientID + @"\'),')";
imgEndDate.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
```

Hope this will work.