# Invoke ASP.NET TextChanged event from JavaScript using __doPostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-handling, ajax.net, dopostback

Like many others, I'm trying to invoke a .NET control's server-side event from JavaScript.

Specifically, I want to fire the `TextChanged` event on a TextBox named `txtSearch`. Therefore, I'm looking to reach the following event from client-side:

```
protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Having read many answers on SO (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103740/force-server-textchanged-event-from-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936699/asp-net-dopostback-from-javascript)) I have the following JavaScript:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$Container$Main$txtSearch', 'TextChanged');
```

But the server-side event never fires.

I've tried numerous permutations: with the AutoPostBack true and false, with and without the event declared in the server-side instructions on the ASPX (*i.e.* OnTextChanged=""), with the EventValidation turned off in the page declaration, using the ClientID rather than the UniqueID in the EVENTTARGET parameter... but the event is still never fired.

A couple of other points

- the `txtSearch` button control is also the trigger for an UpdatePanel, in case that matters.
- I'm converting existing code, of which there's quite a lot, and am looking for something I can drop onto each page rather than converting the code-behind events to PageMethods.

Can anyone tell me what more I need to do?

Comment: To help narrow down the problem - Does the `Page_Load` event get fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this, and it works for me:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="<%= GetOnChangedScript() %>" />
```

The server side `asp:TextBox`, and the client side `input` which fires `__doPostBack` on click. The `__doPostBack` script is generated through [`PostBackOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbackoptions.aspx):

```
protected string GetOnChangedScript()
{
    var options = new PostBackOptions(txtSearch, string.Empty);
    options.AutoPostBack = true;
    options.RequiresJavaScriptProtocol = true;
    var script = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(options);
    return script;
}
```

The `txtSearch_TextChanged` event handler fires when the value of text box is changed, and the `submit` button is clicked.

But note, for controls like `TextBox` the text is stored in the viewstate; the new text entered by the user stores in the form data. When the `TextBox` load the viewstate data, it gets the old value. This is compared with the new value that comes in the form. If the values are different, the `TextChanged` event is fired. If no, the event handler won't be fired. This is the reason for the `Page_Load` event get fired (postback occured), but `txtSearch_TextChanged` didn't fire due to the value of the `TextBox` didn't change.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion exactly as it appears, and it doesn't hit the TextChanged event, only the Page_Load. There are two other problems with this suggestion: (1) I'm looking to be able to do this entirely in JavaScript rather than adding an extra function to each code-behind where I have to implement this change; (2) I have some custom JavaScript that I want to run before the value of txtSearch is posted back, but having set AutoPostBack="True" I don't get the chance to do this.

Comment: @awj: (1) this is the **correct** way of adding `__doPostBack`-like references. The name of the server-side control can be changed, and then all your snippets won't work. But it's up to you how to paste these blocks. (2) in my example `AutoPostBack` property is not set. The default value for it is `false`, so this feature is off by default. And finally, the **value** of your text box has to be changed since the last postback for server-side events to fire. This is how the server-side events work.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, @Alex, at this stage I'd be willing to implement *anything* that worked. I have now got your code working (I think I ommitted the OnTextChanged attribute previously) and am investigating how I can wire it up with my custom event in order to trigger the postback in specific circumstances.

Comment: @awj, do you mean to trigger the postback for the textbox even if text value doesn't change? If yes, you'll have to analyze post data manually (e.g. in `Page_Load`), and then call `txtSearch_TextChanged` manually too.

Comment: No, I have a custom function whereby a threshold number of characters has to be entered, and then a timeout happens to see whether the user is going to enter any more characters (each key-press resets the timer). Only after this does a postback take place. We did have an Ajax Control Toolkit Extender which did this, and this is what I'm now replacing.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because I'm convinced that the code-behind needs some sort of forewarning that it should allow an event to be triggered, and that this is somehow achieved through Alex's GetOnChangedScript() method. This is really the only difference between the two suggested answers. A sincere thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function initTxtBox(){  $('#<%=txtBox.ClientID%>').on('keyup change', function() {setTimeout('txtpostback()', 0); return false;});}
function txtpostback(){__doPostBack('" + txtCadastreNumber.UniqueID + @"','');
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(initTxtBox);
```

Set auotpostback property to false for your txtbox and AutoEventWireup="true" for your control or page declaration. 
OnTextChanged event  server-side will work too.
if you don't use jquery in your project, let me know and I give you some javascript example without jquery using.

Comment: Thanks Boriss, but that doesn't work for me.
I now have
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" AutoPostBack="False" runat="server" Value="hello world" />
with
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initTxtBox(){  $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').on('keyup change', function() {setTimeout("__doPostBack(this.id,'')", 0); return false;});}
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(initTxtBox);
</script>
at the bottom of the page. I tried your script exactly as is but Firefox gave me a "Useless setTimeout call", so I wrapped __doPostBack in quotes.
Pressing a key now causes a refresh.

Comment: Ok. Now  I check it in my project

Comment: yes you are right error is present :) now I fix it in my project too. But postback event have been occurred.

Comment: I noticed the edit you had made to the ID parameter in the __doPostBack call. I had used your updated suggestion before I wrote my previous comment, and it was this that causes the page to refresh/reload; it still doesn't trigger the TextChanged event.

Comment: I modified script. Now it works without error in FF. You can use it without seTimeout() ( I need it in my project). I have to do some actions before postback too. And OnTextChanged event on server-side fires in my case.

Comment: Still no result, it still only hits the Page_Load event and not the TextChanged event. The setTimeout isn't the problem because __doPostBack *is* triggering a postback; the problem is either that EventValidation is preventing the postback from triggering the event (though I've tried it with EnableEventValidation="False" and that has no noticeable effect) or that, like @Alex has explained in his answer, the code-behind doesn't see that the value of txtSearch has been changed.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that only the __doPostBack script is involved in the postback? Is the rest of your JS only there to attach the __doPostBack to the TextChanged event?

Comment: You can try function txtpostback(){<%=GetOnChangedScript()%>}; in my function as answered @Alex. It  works too; And you can add $('#<%=txtBox.ClientID%>').change() before _doPostBack. This triggers change event on textbox

Comment: for exmple var oldtext=txt.val();  txt.val(somevalue);txt.change(); txt.val(oldtext); __doPostBack. i hope this can helps to change Viewstate. It just to try if textchanged works