# Setting TextBox to ReadOnly prevents postback in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, asp.net-ajax

My ASP.NET code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#addScheduleEffectiveStartDate").datepicker({
            minDate: new Date() // Date must be at least today
        })
   })
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="serviceTypeUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="addScheduleEffectiveStartDate" EventName="TextChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="false" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="addScheduleEffectiveStartDate" OnTextChanged="addScheduleEffectiveStartDate_TextChanged" />
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This works as expected - my event handler is called when I change the date (either by typing in the box or by modifying it from the DatePicker).

I'd like to make the Text Box read only though, so that the user can only modify the text box content through the Date Picker. However, when I do that, the event handler is no longer called.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to manually fire the postback event yourself after you've updated the textbox value.  You can actually leverage the __doPostBack event just like the TextBox does.

```
__doPostBack('addScheduleEffectiveStartDate','')
```

Note that will be the full ClientID used in the doPostBack example above.

Here's a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707003/invoke-asp-net-textchanged-event-from-javascript-using-dopostback) that goes into further detail about invoking a TextChanged event with doPostBack